# Reading Structures (Struct information) in C

Tags: c, struct, arrays

My question is a bit strange. I've given a Client-Server application, where in Client a Structure has been designed and it contains a Character array with size `char values[1000]`. I will receive 1000 bits from Server in terms of `0's and 1's`. In that I would like to read the bit from `885 and 886's position`. How to execute this properly? Coz am getting strange characters when I read at that positions. I think it's because the bits are stored as mass data inside that `values[]` array like `values[1000]={111010101....1}`and not like normal array-> `int abc[2] = {1,2};`.

Is this the reason? Then how can I read `885 and 886's positions` from `values[1000]={111010101....1}`?

Kindly clarify...

Comment: How do you store "bits" in a `char`?

Comment: @Inspired Thanks for your comment. Can you explain please Why can't we?

Comment: you surely can. The question is whether you store 8 bits per single char, or one bit per char, or maybe you do it in some other way (it's not clear from your question).

Comment: Show the C code with which you receive the 1000 bits from the server.  And also show how you currently extract the 885 and 886 'positions'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of confusion here.

Assuming 8-bit `char`s just to keep the confusion down, bits 885 and 886 will be in character 110 (counting from 0, that's the 81st character).

If we index the bits from the LSB as bit 0, then that character has these bits in it:

```
       88888888
bit nr 88888888
       76543210
        **
```

Reading vertically, we find 885 and 886 where indicated with asterisks (`*`).

So, to extract these two bits:

```
const int bit885 = (values[110] & 0x20) >> 5;
const int bit886 = (values[110] & 0x40) >> 6;
```

Comment: _Assuming 8-bit chars just to keep the confusion down_ . i heard char size will be always of 1 Byte.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Dayalrai Yes, that's right. But there's no guarantee that "one byte" is 8 bits, that's why we have `CHAR_BIT` to say how many bits each `char` has. If you think "but but but a byte is always 8 bits" then that's not true in C's terminology, and you can say "octet" when you really mean an 8-bit quantity.

Comment: @unwind +1 for explanation

Answer (score 2):

Your char array contains 8 bits on each position as a char takes up one byte. I suppose that you receive a byte stream from the server? This means that each position takes up 8 bits and you will have to find the correct position by division, e.g.:

```
char c = values[885/8];
```

After this still have to shift or mask the correct bit in those 8 bits. You could find the bit position by modulo division: 885 % 8

Read up on bits and bytes and bit operations (and, or, shift)

Also check out how your data is received on the server and how many bytes you receiv

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you store 8 bits per single `char`, it can be done this way. Its the way we use `PIN` register in ARM.

```
int bitState = 0;
char buff[1000];

//Some execution that updates the buff

bitState = ((buff & (1 << 885)) ? 1 : 0);
if(bitState)
  //DO this;
else
  //DO that;

bitState = ((buff & (1 << 886)) ? 1 : 0);
if(bitState)
  //DO this;
else
  //DO that;
```